# Adding glue records to my registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, glue-record

I have a country specific domain (let say example.me) and when I try to add my own nameserver (ns1.example.me & ns2.example.me) at my country registrar it didn't worked because I only have 1 IPv4 IP and that registrar control panel didn't accept same IP for both different nameserver.

My vps have it's own dns service and dns control panel because I want to make changes at my vps. Adding resources records and so on. So how to solve my problem without forking another 1-2 dollar to buy extra IP? I'm thinking about signing up with free dns service provider but isn't when I do that I can only add A, NS MX records and etc. etc. at my external dns provider dashboard?

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You really really do not want to have one single server as the only nameserver for your domain. The reason your registrar requires you to have two separate IPs is that you should have at least two different servers handling DNS for your system. Otherwise, if anything happens with your server, the network to it, or any error in your DNS configuration on that one server will mean that your entire site will be unreachable, nobody will be able to queue mail to you.

In short - DNS is the most important thing for your domain. It's worth paying to get it done right.

Comment: Yeah I know the logical reason why they did that but I was hoping I could save some dollar... It was just a test site with my vps and I don 't think it worth it to fork another dollar and perhaps I could find another workaround... Upvote vor the worthiness of your answer.

Comment: Thanks :-) In a similar case, I had a friend who was in the same position and we traded secondary dns's with one another, so my server was secondary for his domain and his was for mine. That's definitely the cheapest way to do it... Or maybe your server hosting company can be your secondary.